# Error Andrid studiio Task :app:mergeDebugResources Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android-studio

Error 1.

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> C:\Users\João.gradle\caches\transforms-3\14c8f4d9859ab4670012378cf62d3d56\transformed\material-1.10.0\res\values\values.xml:1182:4: Invalid  for given resource value.

line: 30dp

```
<dimen name="mtrl_transition_shared_axis_slide_distance">30dp</dimen>
<item name="material_ic_keyboard_arrow_next_black_24dp" type="drawable">@drawable/material_ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp</item>
<item name="material_ic_keyboard_arrow_previous_black_24dp" type="drawable">@drawable/material_ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp</item>
```

Error 2:

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\medidordeIMC\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@52ab8ce1.). Check logs for more details.

Eu tentei excluir as linhas, mas mesmo assim o problema continuou.